# Can I edit the Info.plist of an App so that is always starts hidden?

Tags: macos

Well, the title says it all:

**Can I edit the `Info.plist` of an App so that is always starts hidden?**

Answer (score 5):

Open the info.plist in textedit and check if the key "LSUIElement" exist.  If not, then add the following piece of code.

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

If it does, then just change the key from `<true/>` to `<false/>`.

Comment: I have changed the permission using chmod. Yet, I can't save changes because the file is locked.

Comment: Save the file to your desktop, then copy it to the original location

Comment: I've tried this with the Twitter.app. Now I have to enter the password every time I open twitter....

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Note the change I made so that your markup actually shows up plain. Stack Exchange tries to render html tags automatically, so it just ate your tags. Use a 4 space prefix to denote blocks (across multiple lines) of code, or backtick pairs to denote inline code lines.

Comment: This does not make the app start hidden (i.e. like `Cmd-H`), but removed the Dock icon and menu bar.

Comment: Just a comment that the last sentence in the answer above is misleading. It says to change the key from true to false. However, if you want the icon NOT to show in the dock, you set the value to true (as shown in the code snippet of the answer).