# In Fullscreen, disable auto-hiding Mac menu bar

Tags: macos, mouse, menu-bar, fullscreen, virtualbox

(on latest Mavericks)

While in VirtualBox (Ubuntu) fullscreen, on a Mac host, each time the mouse goes near the top, the Mac auto-hide menu bar appears - and I want to prevent that, or at least, since it's the annoying component, reduce the time it takes to that menu to disappear when the mouse goes down [currently it's ~1 seconds].

Ideally the time needed to trigger that menu should be higher than currently [instant] - eg like keeping the mouse on top for 1 whole second.

Illustration below shows the Ubuntu menu that has been overridden by the Mac menu when the mouse hits the top of the screen.

[image: Ubuntu in VBox fullscreen - mouse hits the top...]

There are already a few questions like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) that are either old or not answered.

Any progress in Maverics, near 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems someone found a working solution, at last.

First,

- close your VMs
- Quit VirtualBox

then as *root* (or `sudo ...`)

- copy the file somewhere as backup, then edit (eg `vi`) `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist`
- and add the line shown in the middle

the line `<key>LSUIElement</key> <string>1</string>` to be inserted between `LSCanProvideIMVideoDataSource` and `NSHighResolutionCapable`

```
<key>LSCanProvideIMVideoDataSource</key>    <true/>
<key>LSUIElement</key> <string>1</string>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>          <true/>
```

save, then start VirtualBox again (I didn't have to log out/reboot).

The VM will not show anymore among the opened apps icons, but you can double click the VM in the VirtualBox to switch to it.

The whole post by *Maestro* is [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21676).

Comment: do you happen to know if there's a similar hack for the dock?

Comment: @TinMan Not sure about the dock, but at least you can easily set it up to be left / right / down from the Mac interface, if that bothers you where it is now

Answer (score 0):

From the parallels forum, but could be a goer?

> If you don't want the dock or menu to show up in Mac OS X full screen
>   then you need to turn on active screen corners and then set the screen
>   corners to not have any associated action.
>
> (From the menu select "Virtual Machine" > "Configure...". Then select
>   "Options" from the toolbar and then "Full Screen" from the list on the
>   left side of the window. Check "Active Screen Corners" and select "-"
>   for each screen corner.)

[Parallels Forum - Answer #4](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?208334-Disable-Apple-Menu-amp-Dock-In-Lion-Full-Screen&p=558049&viewfull=1#post558049)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in latest Mavericks / VirtualBox (this answer is for Parallels actually).

Comment: The virtualisation software being used is Oracle VirtualBox, not Parallels Desktop.