# After info.plist setting <key>LSUIElement</key> <string>1</string>, how do I quit the application

Tags: virtualbox

I've set the info.plist to have an LSUIElement key value of 1.

As described here:

[In Fullscreen, disable auto-hiding Mac menu bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114958/in-fullscreen-disable-auto-hiding-mac-menu-bar)

If I fullscreen the virtualbox application using the green fullscreen icon, it will take the fullscreen but have no menu bar associated with it.  I can exit back to the normal desktop area using command-tab but then VirtualBox is not visible anywhere from within the dock.  I can get back to VirtualBox using mission control.

Once in this state, short of logging out and logging back in, is there a way to un-fullscreen the virtualbox window? or quit virtualbox?

Comment: Have you tried using Esc key?

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to quit the VirtualBox console and leave the virtual box vms open by using the activity monitor, finding the virtualbox process and then choosing quit.  Relaunching the virtualbox console, launches it in non-maximized mode.