# Is there any way to adjust the automatic appearance of the menu in a full screen application on Mac 10.10.4

Tags: menu-bar, fullscreen

I'd like to adjust the automatic appearance of the menu bar on my MacOS 10.10.4 so that it doesn't repeatedly show itself when it isn't wanted and I'm just aiming for an in application tab and accidentally hitting the top of the screen.

It seems this is set to a fraction of second, meaning I have to be really precise to hit a tab or pull the pointer away to let the menu slide back in so I can access the option.

Adjusting the time delay would be best, though I'd also be happy with disabling this poorly implemented feature and showing the menu on a key-click

Comment: Related to; possibly a duplicate of: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/70985/12285

Comment: looks good, ironically, as I opened it, and the recommended app in it's answer, I had to go for tabs in full screen and both times I triggered the menu

Comment: tbh, I was hoping they'd fixed this bug in the latest version