# Can you make the menu bar never show while in full screen already?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, fullscreen

4 years ago, [I asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) if it is possible to stop the menu bar from showing while in full screen. The issue is that, on tabbed applications, whenever I try to click a tab, the menu bar appears above it causing me to click in the wrong place. Half a decade later and I'm still deeply frustrated with this issue. Is there any way to do it yet?

Here is what I am talking about:

[image: Menu bar appearing on tabbed applications]

Comment: Not that I know of. :/

Comment: Can't you hide the menu bar with OS X el Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround... Go into System Preferences. Select "General." Towards the top, there is a place you can set the menu bar to "Automatically hide and show the menu bar."

[image: screencap]

Comment: But that still causes the menu bar to sneak in when I try to click a tab on chrome full screen...

Comment: Ah, I see. I will continue to see what I can find.

Comment: The menu bar is essential  for an application. I think  that Apple will not give a way to do this until all of the computers will be tablets.