# Chrome: When menubar displays, webpage shifts down

Tags: google-chrome, menu-bar

All of a sudden, a couple weeks ago, I've noticed that whenever I hover my mouse at the top of my chrome browser while in fullscreen, when the top menu bar appears it shifts the whole webpage a couple inches down. It's a really clumsy interface experience - when reading ebooks on google play books, to accidentally hover my mouse to the top of the webpage causes the page to shift and subsequently reformat me to a new page in the book.

The menu bar used to just come down over the webpage, covering whatever inch or two it took up. Now the whole thing reformats. Any solutions to this?

I understand this is is similar to other threads, but what I'm looking for is not for the menu bar to be there permanently, just that when I hover my mouse, it doesn't reformat the page as it is now doing.

I have added a GIF, hopefully you can see the effect I'm talking about. The recording isn't perfect but, basically, no overlay. Just slides the whole webpage down.
[image: I have added a GIF, hopefully you can see the effect I am talking about.]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I've seen someone posting a screen recording actually. Can someone tell me how to attach one?

Comment: You need a screen recorder that saves as animated GIF: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/screen-recording-gif-video-tool-for-mac-os-x

Comment: you sure this wasn't always the case? there's a question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) that was last edited in 2017 that shows a gif with same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested it on my Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

on OS X High Sierra 10.13.6

and it works just fine !

Update your Chrome and OS X

and disable Chrome add on's to test.

Go to `chrome://flags/` and Reset to Defaults.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and it is highly annoying (even finally made a StackExchange account just for this). I am using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and OS X High Sierra 10.13.6. To be clear; the expected behaviour is that the menu bar overlays chrome when you move your mouse there (in my case it would overlap the open tabs). This is what happens e.g. in Intellij. Disabling add-on's did not work. Anyone else with suggestions?

Comment: @Maxim that is correct, it supposed to overlay not push the window down. Sometimes it helps to test it with creating new user account on your Mac, which would eliminate some interfering apps you have in the original account. I know it is a cumbersome method, but we do not know the apps you have.

Comment: @maxim my issue exactly