# How to disable the title bar in fullscreen?

Tags: macos, window-manager, fullscreen

In MacOS Monterey when my cursor goes on the menu bar while in full screen the title bar for the application drops down. This makes it rather difficult to quickly switch tabs, as when drag my cursor up it hits the top of the screen dropping the title bar which blocks me from switching tabs. How can I disable this and just control the window with hotkeys or the menu bar?

***I am talking about the title bar, not the menu bar.***

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the Menu Bar never show while in Full Screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen)

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the menu bar, but the title bar of the application. Look at the picture I attached.

Comment: Are you using latest version of Brave? Mine is 1.32.113 and does NOT have your problem. I suspect that applications needs to be aware of this full screen behaviour and push layout down appropriately. Safari pushes the heading (including tab bar) but not the page content.  Brave (current version) pushes down the page as well as the tab bar etc.  Mail does nothing (like your version of Brave).

Comment: Yes I do I have the latest version, this is a problem I have with all non apple apps.

Comment: I think you should be talking to the app developers about making them compatible with Monterey's full screen behaviour. Double check your Brave version. You can also turn off (for all apps) the auto hide in System prefs > Dock & MenuBar