# Avoid "not authorized to send Apple events to System Events (-1743)" in MacOS Ventura from keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, security, automator, fullscreen

I am attempting to follow the instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) to create a keyboard shortcut that toggles a window to full screen with no menu bar. On MacOS Ventura 13.4, I always get the error "Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)." Normally, I would expect a prompt to appear the first time the action is run asking me to give permission, but that never happens. I also do not see any place in Security/Privacy settings (e.g. under Automation) where I can allow this action. I've also tried running the compiled app from the terminal command line (i.e. "open fullscreen.app") and I get the same error there, with no option to give permission. I've tried adding the app under Privacy/Security-->Accessibility, but it makes no difference. How can I get around the 1743 error?